# jQuery - .click() and .toggle()

Tags: jquery, click

i would like to show an image when a user click on a link and, when he clicks again, to hide it. Here some code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <img id="c0" src="images/item-1.png">
  <img id="c1" src="images/item-2.png">
 </div>
</div>

<a id="ac1" href="#">Link</a>

$('#c1').hide();
$('#ac1').click(function(){
    $('#c0').hide();
    $('#c1').show();
});
```

It works and its simple. But it doesnt allow to hide the image  when someone click again the link.
I would like to know if there is a solution that I can apply to other situations.
Thank you

Comment: just use `$('#c0').toggle();
    $('#c1').toggle();`

Comment: Have a look at `.toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img style="display:none" id="c0" src="images/item-1.png">
        <img id="c1" src="images/item-2.png">
    </div>
</div>

$( "DIV.col-md-12" ).click(function() {
    $( "DIV.col-md-12 IMG" ).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the toggle() function:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <img id="c0" src="images/item-1.png">
  <img id="c1" src="images/item-2.png">
 </div>
</div>

<a id="ac1" href="#">Link</a>

$('#c1').hide();
$('#ac1').click(function(){
    $('#c0').toggle(speed);
    $('#c1').toggle(speed);
});
```